# How do you save replays in Tekken Tag Tournament 2?

Tags: tekken-tag-tournament-2

How do you save replays in TTT2?

PS3 Offline Arcade Mode specifically (not sure if that warrants the ps3 tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replays are automatically stored, and can be saved by accessing them under Profile → Replay Theater → All Replays, selecting them and pressing the Start button.

However, only VS battle replays (online or offline) can be saved, so *there is no in-game solution for saving arcade mode replays*.

Note: old replays that have not been saved will be deleted automatically (the marquee on the menu item reads: "The oldest entries will be deleted first.").

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to simply export the replays. You'll have to record the matches by hooking up a game capture device like [Dazzle](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815144044) or a [Hauppauge HD PVR](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815116030) and playing back the replays.

Comment: I don't know how to save them in the first place.

Comment: First twenty replays of online matches and vs battle are always saved automatically. Should be under Profile>Replays>All replays. It's been a while since I played the game so might be wrong regarding where it's saved.

Comment: I see. It's limited to vs only.